# Is it safe to alter the underlying encrypted files for a live mounted ecryptfs volume?

Tags: linux, encryption, synchronization, ecryptfs

I want to do live synchronization of an encrypted directory with a server, such that the server only sees encrypted data.

Suppose I put the underlying ecryptfs data in:

```
/home/user/.Private
```

And I mount that directory at:

```
/home/user/unlocked
```

Can I update the files in `.Private` (e.g. using rsync) and expect `unlocked` to reflect the changes?  Or is this going to just mess things up?  Are there better alternatives for live synchronization of encrypted data?

---

UPDATE to clarify:

I want to only ever transmit encrypted data to the server -- the server is not trusted.  So I want to see:

```
 client <-- encrypted data --> server
```

There may be more than one client updating (decrypted) files; hence the live-synchronization desire:

```
 client1
        \
         \--- encrypted data --\
                                \
                                 server
                                /
         /--- encrypted data --/
        /
 client2
```

So the client has a directory containing encrypted files -- chunked the way ecryptfs does it:

```
/home/client1/.Private/
                 |--- ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.Fabcde.../
                 |                                    |--- ECRYPTFS_FNEK_...
                 |
                 |--- ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.Flaksd.../
                                                      |--- ...
```

This is mounted with ecryptfs:

```
/home/client1/unlocked/
                 |--- secret_file_1
                 |--- secret_file_2
```

Now, client1 is busily making changes to files in `unlocked`.  When the client makes changes, the underlying encrypted files in `.Private` change as well.  So a local inotify or some such notices the changes and rsyncs the encrypted base files in `.Private` to server.  The server, aware that client2 is also listening, notifies client2 that it should pull changes.

So my concern is: If client2 pulls down the underlying encryptfs chunked files into .Private while it is mounted in `unlocked`, I suspect this will cause problems, no?  This would require client2 to unmount `unlocked` prior to syncing, which defeats the whole "live synchronizaton" idea.

If so, what are good alternative techniques for efficient syncing of diffs of an encrypted tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Tyler Hicks (one of the maintainers of eCryptfs) it is currently not safe to modify underlying filesystem (lower filesystem in eCryptfs terminology):

> > It would be good if eCryptfs could detect lower file data changes and
> >     update the cache to see the file updated.
>
> Even if we could detect them, how would we mediate them against dirty
>   eCryptfs pages? How do we know what is the most up-to-date data?
>
> Unfortunately, direct modifications to the lower filesystem are simply
>   not supported. If a modification doesn't go through the eCryptfs mount
>   point, we cannot be expected to know about it due to the eCryptfs
>   architecture.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/689030

Answer (score 1):

To update files in the ecryptfs filesystem you need to update them in the mount point - in the encrypted filesystem you would need to update the entire thing at once, as it has no concept of files or directories - it is just a large chunk of data.

Yes, you can use rsync to back that data up somewhere, but in order to read or write a particular file you need to mount it.

You can mount it from various different places (probably best not to try this simultaneously :-) so why not use a shell script which mounts, rsync's the relevant files and unmounts whenever relevant files are updated?

useful info **[here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_Encryption_with_eCryptfs)**

Comment: "in the encrypted filesystem you would need to update the entire thing at once, as it has no concept of files or directories - it is just a large chunk of data.":  I'm pretty sure that's not true.  According to the article you link to, ecryptfs is a "Stacked Cryptographic File System", which is distinct from a block-device encryption which it sounds like you're describing.  The difference: http://ecryptfs.sourceforge.net/ecryptfs-faq.html#compare .  I've updated the question to provide more detail.

Comment: @user67641 - ah yes, you can do it that way as well. My bad - I don't. In eitehr case you should be correct (caveat - I haven't tested this yet): client 2 would need to unmount prior to syncing. And I don't know a workaround - so my answer isn't going to help you much at all. Will try and get some time to test it.